# Ant Migration tool - Failed to login

Tags: ant

### I am trying to retrieve code from salesforce using ant salesforce mignration tool but I am seeing below error. I am running this from  a office firewall

C:\Continous Integration\sample>ant retrieveCode
Buildfile: C:\Continous Integration\sample\build.xml

retrieveCode:
[sf:retrieve] Note: use ant -verbose to get more information on the failure

BUILD FAILED
C:\Continous Integration\sample\build.xml:109: Failed to login: Failed to send r
equest to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0

### Total time: 22 seconds

I am using salesforce migration tool version 39.0, Java 1.8 and ant 1.10.

I tried using java proxy settings and I did try creating environment variable ANT_OPTS and I also tried adding proxy setting in build.xml but nothing worked for me.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: The error says failed to send request. I would guess that this means it never reached salesforce and probably got blocked within your firewall.